# Can you use a shunt to turn off a disconnect switch?

Tags: power, switches, shunt

I was wondering if a shunt could be used to turn off a disconnect switch such as [this ABB OT40F3](https://new.abb.com/products/1SCA104902R1001/ot40f3)?

I am designing something with high voltage (480) and couldn't find good options for relays that could handle it so I could use them as an emergency stop with a contactor.

I was considering using a shunt. I know it can be used for a molded case circuit breaker since a shunt sends a magnetic pulse that trips the breaker, which makes me almost certain that I can't use it for a disconnect switch but wanted to double check.

Comment: what do you mean by `turn off a disconnect switch`?

Comment: I mean when connected to a molded case circuit breaker, a shunt, when activated, fires a magnetic pulse that trips the breaker. Would this magnetic pulse turn off a disconnect switch?

Comment: The shunt causes the breaker to 'trip' to the off position. A disconnect switch does not have a 'trip' mechanism - it's just a switch.

Comment: Post a diagram of what you want to implement and what you have now.